# get touch data (and not just keystrokes) when using keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, ontouchlistener

I want to obtain touch information (by obtaining motionEvents and not just click, keyUp,...) when I am using the keyboard on a TextEdit view.

I solved this for button views like this:

```
   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);      
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Save event information (such as pressure, size,..) here
            return false;
        }   
    });
```

and so I am trying to use the same approach with KeyboardView with no luck

```
    KeyboardView keyboard = (KeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboardView);
    keyboard.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Save event information (such as pressure, size,..) here
            return false;
        }   
    });
```

The code seems to never get inside the onTouch function when the keyboard is visible. Here's the layout.xml

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_answer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@string/edit_answer" />

 <Button
    android:id= "@+id/buttonSubmit"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/button_submit" />


<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: What do you aim to do when a keyboard key is touched? I just doubt that going through the pain trying to implement that makes sense.

Comment: override onTouchEvent or dispatchTouchEvent

Comment: I want to do behavioral analysis research. I dont need it for my app per se but I need to measure the data.

Comment: I am missing  
Keyboard myKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.layout.keyboard);
keyboard.setKeyboard(myKeyboard); 

but I need to include R.layout.keyboard but I want it to be the default. Where can I find it?